# Is there a Way to have an October instance with a Laravel app working together in the same project?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I know that October is based in laravel, I was wondering, is there a Way to have an October instance with a Laravel app working together in the same project. The thing is I need to create a more elaborated system and I was planning to do it with laravel and Blade but I also need a web page with an CMS to manage the content and stuff like reservations... Thanks

Comment: Yes, entirely possible. https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/347

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible.

Create a plugin, create a `routes.php` file. Add whatever routes you want.

October doesn't support asset publishing so you'll need to figure out a way around that if that is required.